# Cloudflare Loadtest 520 error

Tags: cloudflare, locust

I'm using locust to loadtest my application through Cloudflare.

When my test hits ~ 2k users I start getting 520 response errors.

Is that Cloudflare DDoS protection or I need to tune Up my web/app server?

I see no errors on nginx logs.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely a firewall just in front of your webserver. It's seeing a lot of traffic from very few IP addresses (CloudFlare's). Have you whitelisted CF's IPs?

Comment: I didn't do that. You mean on nginx config or my VPN cloud?

Comment: That I don't know... probably not nginx though.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out. Thanks!